My spouse has been asked to submit his rental agreement for document verification of my spouse visa, but he lives in a small flat
I live in India and my husband has been working in Germany for the last 2 years. I applied for dependent visa and now the application has reached Germany and they've asked for additional documents on email, which are mainly rent agreement and his employment contract. He lives in a flat of 21 sqm. I think the minimum requirement is 26 sqm for two people. While he's looking for a flat, is it okay if he submits the current agreement or should he take some time and make sure he gets a bigger flat? Will the application get rejected for this?

Typically if visa rules state a minimum for something, be that square footage, income, savings etc, failing to show that you meet the minimum stated in the rule will result in a refusal. Immigration authorities are not likely to leave the application pending for an indefinite amount of time to allow your spouse to find a flat that fulfils the space requirement.


He lives in a flat of 21 sqm. I think the minimum requirement is 26 sqm for two people

This will depend on which state your husband lives in.
It is either 24 or 18 sqm for 2 adults, whereby it can be up to 10% less

21.6 sqm or 16.2 sqm

Therefore in Berlin, Bremen, Hessen and Nordrhein-Westfahlen, 21 sqm would cause no problem, but elsewhere the 21 sqm is 12.5% under the minmum requirement.

The general rule is defined in the General administrative regulation on the Residence Act (AVwV AufenthG) point 2.4.2 as being

12 sqm per adult and 10 sqm per child under the age of 6

Where state rules exist (that are lower), those rules apply.
As of 2017, Berlin, Bremen, Hessen and Nordrhein-Westfahlen have such rules:

9 sqm per adult (and for Hessen also for children under the age of 6)
6 sqm per child under the age of 6 in Berlin, Bremen and Nordrhein-Westfahlen



Allgemeine Verwaltungsvorschrift zum Aufenthaltsgesetz

General administrative regulation on the Residence Act

2.4.1
Die Obergrenze bildet das Sozialwohnungsniveau, d. h.es darf keine bessere Ausstattung verlangt werden, als sie auch typischerweise Sozialwohnungen in der jeweils entsprechenden Region aufweisen. Die Untergrenze bilden die auch für Deutsche geltenden Rechtsvorschriften der Länder, also z. B. die Wohnungsaufsichtsgesetze oder in Ermangelung solcher Gesetze das allgemeine Polizei- bzw. Ordnungsrecht.

The upper limit is the social housing standard, i.e. no better facilities may be required than those typically found in social housing in the respective region. The lower limit is the legal provisions of the states that also apply to Germans, e.g. the housing supervision laws or, in the absence of such laws, the general police or regulatory law.

2.4.2
Ausreichender Wohnraum ist – unbeschadet landesrechtlicher Regelungen – stets vorhanden, wenn für jedes Familienmitglied über sechs Jahren zwölf Quadratmeter und für jedes Familienmitglied unter sechs Jahren zehn Quadratmeter Wohnfläche zur Verfügung stehen und Nebenräume (Küche, Bad, WC) in angemessenem Umfang mitbenutzt werden können.
Eine Unterschreitung dieser Wohnungsgröße um etwa zehn Prozent ist unschädlich. Wohnräume, die von Dritten mitbenutzt werden, bleiben grundsätzlich außer Betracht; mitbenutzte Nebenräume können berücksichtigt werden.

Sufficient living space is always available – regardless of state law – if twelve square meters of living space are available for each family member over the age of six and ten square meters for each family member under the age of six, and if ancillary rooms (kitchen, bathroom, toilet) can be used to an appropriate extent.
A reduction of around ten percent in this apartment size is harmless. Living spaces that are used by third parties are generally not taken into account; ancillary rooms that are used by others can be taken into account.



Sources:

2017-08-04: Deutscher Bundestag - Mindestwohnfläche pro Person in Mietwohnungen Sachstand (PDF)

Berlin, Bremen, Hessen, Nordrhein-Westfahlen

per adult: 9 sqm




Allgemeine Verwaltungsvorschrift zum Aufenthaltsgesetz (AVwV AufenthG)

download of PDF


VIS Berlin - WoAufG Bln | Landesnorm Berlin | Gesamtausgabe | Gesetz zur Beseitigung von Wohnungsmißständen in Berlin (Wohnungsaufsichtsgesetz - WoAufG Bln) in ... | gültig ab: 21.03.1990


Law to eliminate housing deficiencies in Berlin §7 Occupancy
(1) Apartments may only be let or used if there is a living space of at least 9 square metres for each person and a living space of at least 6 square metres for each child up to the age of six.


(+1) Very useful info. It seems the OP already submitted a visa application so just waiting to find something else could be difficult. What would be the best course of action is if the apartment doesn't meet the requirements? Stall (and for how long?), pull the application or submit the additional document anyway?

@Relaxed Much depends on the circumstances (local housing market etc). The husband should contact his responsible immigration official and ask, since in most cases the application will land on their desk. The exact size is important, mostly 1/100 of a meter (such as: 21.12m²), as written in the rent contract. Based on their answer, the husband can then decide how to proceed. Anything else would be pure speculation.

Yes, your spouse needs to show they can house you. The exact square meters vary by federal state. Most federal states have requirements of between 9 and 12m² per adult, make sure to check your states requirements before you consider any action.
This is not a fixed number, it is a guideline. If your spouse had been living in a slightly too small flat for the last two years, I would have said you can try, maybe you meet a sympathetic clerk who won't make you move for half a square meter. But if you are living in a state that requires 24m² it is no longer inside their tolerances. You have to understand that 21 m² is tiny. When I moved out from my parents when I had my first job as a 20 year old, my first appartment paid by my own money was more than double that size. Just for me as a single person on my first job and with less money during the probation period.
Your spouses flat is what Germans would colloquially refer to as a "Wohnklo" (translated: a toilet you can live in), because it is so small, it is basically a bathroom with some furniture. Your spouse made a very good economic decision because they probably save money wherever then can to finance all the paperwork and flights and move. But now is the time to change that. They have to move to an appartment that can house the both of you, comfortably. Not just the bare minimum to get by, hoping for administration to let it slip. For the clerk to check their box without complaints or delays and for the two of you not to go mad being stuck in a tiny cell with nice wallpaper.
The German (and I guess any other) administration does not work on the honor system. There is no "I don't fulfil this criteria, but I promise I will do better" checkbox on forms. Your spouse needs to show they can house you, showing anything else will get their application rejected or at least put on hold. As I said the clerks have some leeway, I would assume that if your spouse showed them a signed lease agreement of a larger flat for a point in the future when they expect you, that should work out too, and at worst put your application on hold until that date, not rejected.
But you need this lease agreement before the application can proceed. For a spousal visa (officially: family reunification) there is no way around it.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
